# How to make field visibility in Kentico forms work based on two conditions

Tags: macros, kentico

I am trying to make field visibility in my online form show up based on two criteria.
I have a check box with 4 items and I want the next field to show up if either field one or field one and two are selected.

The right dependent field boxes are all ticked.

I have tried the following:

```
aquatic_type.Value == "25m pool" || aquatic_type.Value == ("50m pool","25m pool")

aquatic_type.Value == "25m pool" || aquatic_type.Value == ("50m pool" && "25m pool")
```

It will then work if I only select 25m pool but if I select 25m and 50m the field won't show up at all.

Can someone provide me with the structure for how OR works, and two criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your macro should look like this:

```
aquatic_type.Value == "25m pool" || aquatic_type.Value == "50m pool"
```

Kentico K# Macro syntax is very similar in nature to C#

Also since your field can contain both "25m pool" and "50m pool" you might try checking either value like so:

```
aquatic_type.Value.Contains("25m pool") || aquatic_type.Value.Contains("50m pool")
```

Comment: Hi Brendan, That works perfectly if I want the 25m and 50m to show if either 25m or 50m are selected, however I actually want it to be If you select the 25m only, you only get the 25m field, but if you select the 25m and the 50m field you get both 25m and 50m. Similarly if you select just the 50m field you only get the 50m field show up and if you select 50m and 25m, you get both the 50m and 25m show up. Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Brenden, Got it to work, using your simple Contains rule. All I needed to do was aquatic_type.Value.Contains("25m pool") on the 25 field and aquatic_type.Value.Contains("50m pool") on the 50m field. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to upvote the answer and mark it as the answer.